# how to make a function for the area of a triangle in R the program?

Tags: math-software

If a, b and c are the lengths of the sides of a triangle, then the area is given by $\sqrt(s(s − a)(s − b)(s − c))$, where s = $\frac{1}{2}$( a + b + c).
a) Write a function called triangle which takes as input a, b and c and returns the area of a triangle.

If tried to put this into r-studio  so far:

--

area_triangle <- function (a,b,c) {area <- sqrt[s(s − a)(s − b)(s − c)]
s=.5*(a+b+c)
return(area)}

area_triangle(1,3,5)

--

but it keeps giving errors.
if someone can please exlpain.

Comment: Did you try to use $s$ before you defined $s$?

Comment: Try writting first `s <- (a+b+c)/2`, then `area <- sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-b))`, and finally `return(area)`.

Comment: "*it keeps giving errors*"  If you look at the errors, do they have any information about what sort of error they were?  It very likely told you what you did wrong already.

Comment: @azif00 I tried what you wrote, but now it gave me this message "Warning message:
In sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) : NaNs produced"